# Reload Parent page once time met

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to reload a parent page once the start time is met then reload once an end time is met.

I've got a bit of javascript that reloads the this page every 10 seconds.

which loads the schedule

```
$startTime = '9:30';
$endTime = '10:00';
if ($current_date>=$startDate && $current_date<$endDate){
    if ($current_time >= $startTime && $current_time < $endTime){
        if($current_day == $mon_arr[$i] || $current_day == $tue_arr[$i] || $current_day == $wed_arr[$i] || $current_day == $thu_arr[$i] || $current_day == $fri_arr[$i] || $current_day == $sat_arr[$i] || $current_day == $sun_arr[$i]){
            if ($current_time == $startTime || $current_time == $endTime){
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\r\n";
                echo "parent.location.reload(true);\r\n";
                echo "</script>\r\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
<script>
    var timer;
    function refreshPage(){
       if(timer)
          clearInterval(timer)
          timer = setTimeout(refreshPage,10000) 
      location.reload(true);
    }
    refreshPage();
</script>
```

This works, but just loops continuously.

I'm sure this is glaringly obvious.

has anyone got any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: How this can work?: `$startTime = 9:30;`

Comment: Use setTimeout on the client with a number of milliseconds from start

Comment: this is how its recorded in the DB
then I've formatted the date / time to match.
$current_date = date("d/m/Y");
$current_day = date("D");
$current_time = date("H:i");

I know I would of been better just putting it as milliseconds in the DB

Comment: _It would have been better_ yes

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>setTimeout('top.location = \'yoursite.php\'', 10000);</script>
```

Use this to reload your page every 10 seconds, for example.

Comment: location.reload(1) will work and no need for the escaped quotes

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks! I guess I've always used this just in case I wanted to redirect a user to a different page after a while.